# children movieclips doesn't show its width and height according to parent movieclip

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, parent

I have placed 3 movieclips named mcParent, mcChild1, mcChild2 and 1 textbox in flash. child are childrens of parent movie clip. child1 and child2 both are of sizes 300 whereas parent movieclip is 600px, textbox is placed inside child2 movie clip . I have made the flash to auto resize according to the screen area. Everything works well, but after resize it resizes parent and all childrens and textbox which is correct. The problem is with the correct placement of textbox on mcChild2. I have seen that after resize, mcParent width and scalex both changes but the child clips doesn't changed its sizes even they are stretched but there sizes are not updated due to which I am unable to get the exact location of where to place the textbox.

Any help would be appreciated to get the exact size of the child clips after resize.

Thanks.

Comment: how exactly do you resize your flashmovie? do you scale the whole thing or really resize it?

Comment: i resized it according to stage. Scaled it to NO_SCALE and aligned to top_left. then detected resize event and put code to resize the contents accordingly to fill the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the size of the parent movieclip in this case.

Another not-so-clean alternative is to put a small (1x1 square) movieclip **inside** the parent, as an indicator to where the textfield should be placed. Then, on stage resize you'll have to use `localToGlobal` to know the location of that small mc *after* the dimensions changed. Use that info to position the textfield.

Comment: on which movieclip should I call localToGlobal? I have mcChild1 inside mcParent and wanted to know x,y coordinate of mcChild1. should I use like this mcParent.localToGlobal(new Point(mcChild1.x,mcChild1.y)) or should I use like this mcChild1.localToGlobal(new Point(mcChild1.x, mcChild1.y))?

Comment: I got it work. I used mcParent.localToGlobal(new Point(mcParent.mcChild1.x,mcParent.mcChild1.y)) to get local point of mcChild1 according to stage coordinate on which mcParent is placed. Thanks a lot Makram. :)